# Why does Scala separate symbols and letters in identifiers, and can I change this?

Tags: scala

I'm thinking of using Scala for an internal DSL (ie, the DSL is really Scala) for musical composition. I'd want to use identifiers with characters like the sharp sign, ♯ (U+266F). Looks like this is not possible:

```
val c♯0 = 13
```

does not parse. The closest I can get is:

```
val c0_♯ = 13
```

I don't like it. What's the rationale for forcing identifiers to be named like this?

Comment: Note that `#` is one of a few single-character punctuation that are reserved in Scala. Others include `:`, `.`, `,`, `(`, `)`, `{`, `}`, `;`. There is a flip side to this. Absolutely _any_ string of symbols may be used as a name by enclosing it in back-ticks (a little hard to use here...).

Comment: FWIW, I think `val \`c♯0\` = 13` is still acceptable.

Comment: Oh, I see now you're using the Unicode music symbol, not the ASCII `#`.

Comment: Thought about making it a method named `♯` ? This way you can pimp your "Musical Note", and it would return newly transformed note like in `val c_sharp = c.♯`.

Comment: Thank you, but in this case I really want to use symbols like C♯0, B♭4, etc. I'll probably go with an external DSL. I may still use Scala for writing the interpreter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scala's grammar tries to cater to a lot of conflicting requirements. In order to make optional any white-space between "operator-like" method names (such as `+`, `/` or `::`) and their arguments on either side, it's necessary to have a way of signifying that a given name contains a mixture of punctuation and alphanumeric characters.

Keep in mind that internal DSLs are not new languages! They're at best illusions of being new languages. They are still Scala.

If you want complete freedom to control the language you provide to your users, you can write a combinator parser or use an external parser generator.

For anyone involved in language processing in Scala, I highly recommend you check out [Kiama](http://code.google.com/p/kiama/) before rolling your own narrowly focused, single-purpose language processing code. Kiama is a gem!